# problem with fread

Tags: c, fread

i am trying to read one byte at a time from a file:

```
size_t result_new = 1;  
char buf6[1];  
if( (result_new = fread(buf6, 1, 1, pFile)) != 1)  
            {  
                printf("result_new = %d\n", result_new);
                printf("Error reading file\n");
                exit(1);
            }
```

`result_new` is becoming 0 and it is printing the error. any idea what can be wrong. im sure `pFile` is fine.

thanks

Comment: I would suggest you to use a buffer of 2 bytes and then try reading the one byte from the file.

Comment: @Ashwini, care to explain why?

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation:

> fread()  and  fwrite()  return  the 
>   number of items successfully read or
>   written (i.e., not the number of
>   characters).  If an error occurs, or
>   the end-of-file is reached, the
>          return value is a short item count (or zero).

So why don't you check error code that will answer your question? You can use [`perror`](http://www.sbras.ru/cgi-bin/www/unix_help/unix-man?perror+3), for example.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need one byte, `getc` would be a much better choice than `fread`. The interface is simpler and it's likely to be a lot faster.

Comment: +1, but you should prefer `fgetc` to `getc`, since the latter could be implemented as a macro that evaluates its `FILE*` parameter more than once.

Comment: @Adam: As such, `getc` could be noticably faster. The only argument is of type `FILE *`, so unless you're passing the return value of a function that returns a `FILE *` or something like `files[i++]`, the number of times the argument is evaluated is probably irrelevant. Such usage seems pretty rare and pathological to me.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fread/ has an example with reading from a file. It is a c++ page but should work for c

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind when using `fread` and `fwrite` that strange errors can occur in some cases when the file is opened for normal text writing. Opening the file for binary will eliminate this potential problem. It's mainly due to "new lines", which seem for some reason to differ between binary and text file reading and writing.